# Import and combine 2 csv and align with a common column id

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I have 2 data sets one with distinct number of rows and columns but has common id's.

Question: I want both data frames to be combined to form a new dataframe that has same number of df1 rows but added extra Age column, values in age columns to be filled as per the id

Example:

```
data = [[1,'Alex',10],[2,'Bob',12],[3,'Clarke',13],[1,'Alex',13],[4,'Jim',13], [3,'Clarke',13]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['id', 'Name','Score'],dtype=int)

data2 = [[1, 20],[2, 22],[3, 19],[4, 21]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['id','Age'],dtype=int)
```

Out:

[image]

No clue where to start

New to python, please help!

Expected Output:

```
   id   Name    Score   Age
0   1   Alex    10      20    
1   2   Bob     12      22
2   3   Clarke  13      19
3   1   Alex    13      20
4   4   Jim     13      21
5   3   Clarke  13      19
```

Comment: `No clue where to start` - [Pandas docs,Getting Started, User Guide, Tutorials](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/)  are excellent and a good place to start. There are even [videos](https://pandas.pydata.org/talks.html#pycon-us-2015).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```py
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, on="id")
   id    Name  Score  Age
0   1    Alex     10   20
1   1    Alex     13   20
2   2     Bob     12   22
3   3  Clarke     13   19
4   3  Clarke     13   19
5   4     Jim     13   21
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "merge".

You should be able to join both csv's by writing:

```
combined_data = df1.merge(df2, on="id")
```

The merge function combines the tables, and the "on" parameter determined on what condition to merge them on.

Answer (score 0):

You use the merge function to merge two dataframe with equal lengths if they have atleast one column in common. In your case it's the ID. So we merge it 'on' ID like so:

```
data = [[1,'Alex',10],[2,'Bob',12],[3,'Clarke',13],[1,'Alex',13],[4,'Jim',13], [3,'Clarke',13]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['id', 'Name','Score'],dtype=int)

data2 = [[1, 20],[2, 22],[3, 19],[4, 21]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['id','Age'],dtype=int)

merged_df = df1.merge(df2, on="id")
```